# Spring 3.1 Cache Abstraction without parameters

Tags: spring, caching

reading about the new [Cache Abstraction](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/) in Spring 3.1, I wanted to apply this feature to my project.

Can I cache the call to a method that has no parameters?

```
@Cacheable("xCache")
public List<X> loadAllX() {
    ...
}
```

The linked blog post states

> a cache lookup is performed using as key the method parameters

so it should not be possible to cache this method, right?

**Short answer:** Yes, methods without any arguments will get cached just like any other methods. I guess there will be exactly one entry in the cache for that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use @Cahceable for non-argument method in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389889/use-cahceable-for-non-argument-method-in-spring)

Answer (score 11):

You can override this behavior by using "*Cache SpEL available metadata*" as described here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context

In your example, you could specify the following:

```
@Cacheable(value = "xCache", key = "#root.methodName") 
public List<X> loadAllX() { 
    ... 
}
```

Which would cache the list of X in the "xCache" with key "loadAllX"