# Use @Cacheable for non-argument method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, annotations

I'm using Spring cache API and was stuck with a problem:
I have a Dao class with CRUD operations and all I want to do is to cache a no-argument method which returns me a Map of objects (Key - id, Value - entity)

```
class Dao implements IDao<Entity>{

    public Map<Integer, Entity> getAllEntities(){ /* retreiving from DB */ }

    public Entity getEntityByKey(Object key) { ... }

    public void insert(Entity entity){...}

    public void update(Entity entity){...}

    public void delete(Entity entity){...}

}
```

Can anybody tell me how exactly (and correctly) can I cache getAllEntities() method to get entities, cache getEntityByKey to get Entity by key and also to be able to update cache when I perform create, update or delete operations ?
And is it possible to use cacheable version of the method getAllEntities after update (using operations insert, update, delete) ?

Comment: An aside - have you considered using Hibernate and it's second-level caching, if this is a common concern across your application?

Comment: No, I use jdbcTemplate and don't have ability to use Hibernate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3.1 Cache Abstraction without parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612820/spring-3-1-cache-abstraction-without-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Dao implements IDao<Entity>{

    @Cacheable(value = "entity.all")
    public Map<Integer, Entity> getAllEntities(){ /* retreiving from DB */ }

    @Cacheable(value = "entity.item", key="#p0")
    public Entity getEntityByKey(Object key) { ... }

    @CacheEvict(value = {"entity.all", "entity.item"}, allEntries=true)
    public void insert(Entity entity){...}

    @CacheEvict(value = {"entity.all", "entity.item"}, allEntries=true)
    public void update(Entity entity){...}

    @CacheEvict(value = {"entity.all", "entity.item"}, allEntries=true)
    public void delete(Entity entity){...}

}
```

Comment: I feel there is room for improvement in spring's caching mechanism. For example @CacheEvict's allEntries=true applies to all the cache. allEntries=true for both "entity.all" and "entity.item". A finer control would be allEntries for "entity.all" and only a single item for "entity.item".

Comment: It doesn't help. If I run getAllEntities() it work with DB (how it's expected). Then, I run insert method and after - getAllEntities() again, but at this time this method doesn't return me cahced version and it starts to work with DB again.

Comment: The most important thing here is calling of getAllEntities() or getEntityByKey() must ALWAYS return me a CACHED version regardless of making insert, update or delete operations. Is it possible to do ? Maybe using EhCache or there are some other workarounds ?

Comment: does multiple calls to the getAllEntities() hit the database or only the first one?

Comment: i think there is a "blocking"/"non-blocking" configuration, return a stale cache, while building a new one. is that what you want? eg. you run your call, it hits the db. you call again. it hits the cache. you do the update. you call again. it returns the cached result, yet at the background it hits the db (for next calls). you call again, it returns new result, but cached (retrieved before the call)

Comment: "does multiple calls to the getAllEntities() hit the database or only the first one? " -  it depends. It touches db ONLY after I try to insert\update\delete smthg

Comment: yes, by another words, getAllEntities must hit DB only one time - when the application runs (let's say it like this). Then calling this method I want to get cached result, always, regardless of performing update or delete operations.

Comment: are you using cache:annotation-driven

Comment: My configurations use EhCache, but annotations are standart - from spring

Comment: can you do a "throw new NullPointerException()" and look at the stack trace to see if its properly configured? Depending on how many AOP you have you should see a few $ProxyXX. One should be transaction. If you have transactional you should see another in your stacktrace. I suspect that your cache configuration might be incorrect.

Comment: That's exact question - how to make the configuration correct to be able to accomplish what i need. It's not a trivial solution what i use, but i suspect what i'm not alone in this battlefield - at least someone has been already faced with the similiar situation. So, still need help here =)

Comment: I entered into same situation but do not know how to get out from it :(